# Eigen::VectorXdを戻り値とする関数の出力を受け取る変数の宣言に、型推論を用いた時の挙動についての疑問

Tags: c++, c++11

＜実行環境＞
 - OS: OSX 10.11.3
 - コンパイラ: clang++ 
以下は、clang++ -vの出力
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
 - 非標準ライブラリとして、Eigenを使用（http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page）
 - C++11の機能を使用
＜コード＞

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class A{
private:
    VectorXd ma;
public:
    A(VectorXd a = VectorXd::Ones(1)){
        ma = a;
    }

    VectorXd geta(){
        return ma;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
   B(VectorXd a = VectorXd::Ones(1)): A(a){
       // In the following line, if you use the type name "VectorXd" and don't use "auto", you can get the normal result. 
       const auto b = 2 * geta();

       // If you release the comment out the following line, even if using the "auto" during initialization of b, you can get the normal result. 
       // const auto c = geta();

       cout << "b = " << b << endl;
       cout << "b = " << b << endl;
   }
};

int main() {
    VectorXd la = 2 * VectorXd::Ones(1);
    cout << "la = " << la << endl;
    B test = B();

    return 0;
}
```

＜実行結果＞

1. 上記のコードをそのまま実行した場合の出力
   la = 2
   b = 2
   b = 4
2. Class Bのコンストラクタ内の変数bの宣言・初期化時に型推論（auto）を使わずに、VectorXdという型を用いた場合の出力
   la = 2
   b = 2
   b = 2
3. 変数bの宣言・初期化時には型推論を使用するが、その次の行でconst auto c = geta()という式を評価する場合の出力
   la = 2
   b = 2
   b = 2

＜質問内容＞
修正を行う前のコードだと、意図していた動作（la及びbの２度の出力結果が同じ値を示す）にならない理由を伺いたです。bに型情報を与えることが解決策になることは、確かめることができましたが、なぜこのような動作になるのかが、未熟な私には理解できません。
ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigenライブラリでは「式テンプレート(ET; Expression Template)」とよばれる[テクニックを利用](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html)しているのですが、この技法は`auto`による変数型推論との相性がよくありません。

[混ぜるな危険! Eigenとauto](http://qiita.com/sakisakira/items/7c6952e59e958cefe7fa) に詳しい説明がありましたのでそちらに譲ります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考サイト「混ぜるな危険! Eigenとauto」はこちらでも参考にさせていただいておりましたが、式テンプレートについては把握していませんでした。公式のページも含めて改めて調べてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Eigenにはあまり詳しくないので，かなり推量が入っていますがご了承ください．

こちらの環境（VS2015）では，型推定を用いた場合のbの型は，

```
class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<struct Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<double>,class Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> const>
```

となっています．つまり，double と VectorXd の演算の式自体を表していることになります．
この`b`を出力した場合，どうやら`b`の式を評価した結果が出力されるようです．
したがって，`b`は出力するたびに評価され，

> la = 2
>   b = 2
>   b = 4

という結果になります．この後`b`を出力し続ければ，b = 8, b = 16 と 2倍になっていきます．`b`という式自体が計算を行う対象となるベクトルが何になるのかは，Eigenの仕組みによります．ただ，この場合に関しては，`b`を評価した結果得られたベクトルが，次の評価のベクトルとして使われているため，値が2倍に変化していき，もし，`const auto c = geta()`という式をはさんだ場合には（この`c`の型はVectorXdになる），評価には`c`の値が使われるようになり，結果として正しくなるようにみえます．ただし，これは偶然だと言ってよいでしょう．

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。osx環境だけではなく、Win環境でも同じことが起こる事がわかりました。"b"を評価した結果得られたベクトルが、次の評価のベクトルとして使われる過程は、yohjpさんが示してくださったEigenにおける式テンプレートや、遅延評価の使用に関わってそうです。